# Configuring Dotnet Feature Management in .Net6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to configure Dotnet Feature Management in VS2022, .net6. However, I am doing everything correct as shown in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x). But I want to configure it from a different configuration section (`Configuration.GetSection("MyFeatureFlags")`).

`AddFeatureManagement` is having an overloaded method with an additional parameter which I am not sure what to pass. How can I solve this ?

[image]

```
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddFeatureManagement(Configuration.GetSection("MyFeatureFlags"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
builder.Services.AddFeatureManagement(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyFeatureFlags"));
```